# FLAT XML of any type using SAX Parser in Java

Tags: java, xml

I am a novice in Java and I have written a code in which I am struggling to fetch the element value inside the tag. for example in the below xml- id = bk001 didn't appear in the output

```
   <book id="bk001">
  <author>Hightower, Kim</author>
  <title>The First Book</title>
  <genre>Fiction</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <pub_date>2000-10-01</pub_date>
  <date>
  <auth_date>
  2000-10-01
  </auth_date>
  <auth_date>
  2000-10-05
  </auth_date>
  </date>
  <review>An amazing story of nothing.</review>
  </book>
```

We can expect XML of any type, we have to convert into a flat structure e.g. CSV

Code written

```
 public class SAX 
 {
Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String,String>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new SAX().printElementNames("input/books_1.xml");
}

public void printElementNames(String fileName) throws IOException 
{
    try {
        SAXParserFactory parserFact = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = parserFact.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() 
        {
            public void startElement(String uri, String lName, String ele,  Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                System.out.print(ele + " ");

                if((attributes.getValue("TagValue"))==null)
               {
                  return;
               }
               else
               {

                System.out.println(attributes.getValue("TagValue"));
               }
            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                String value = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
                if(value.length() == 0) return;
                System.out.println(value);
            }               
        };

        parser.parse(new File(fileName), handler);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Kindly help me with the same. I have tried to search the same on stackoverflow but couldn't get anything concrete.
Agenda of the code is that it should work for any valid XML.
Note - We are not allowed to use external libraries like gson etc.

Comment: do you have a schema(xsd) for this ? You can use JAXB for this !

Comment: No, I don't have the xsd. Its like whatever XML is coming as input we have flatten it

Answer (score 0):

The only attribute that your code is attempting to read is "TagValue", so why would you expect your code to display the value of an "id" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

replace your startElement with:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    System.out.print(qName + " ");

    for(int i=0; i<attributes.getLength();i++) {
        System.out.println(attributes.getQName(i) + " " + attributes.getValue(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked very well. Is it possible, like if I want to collect whole of the information in a HashMap based key value pair collection or something similar. I want to use this collection in other program.